# Initial value problem/ Critical values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am stuck on the following problem.

Consider the initial value problem
$16y′′+24y′+9y=0, y(0)=a, y′(0)=−1.$ Find the critical value of a that separates solutions that become negative from those that are always positive for t>0.

I know how to do this if the unknown variable, $a$, is under the $y'(0)$, and $y(0)$ is given. I approached this question in a similar way, getting my solution $Be^{-3/4t}+Cte^{-3/4t}$. I then set B equal to $a$, because $y(0)$ would cancel out the second term. Using the second IC, I get $C = \frac{3}{4}a-1$, or $a = \frac{4}{3}(C+1)$, but the solution requires an exact answer without variables.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After incorporating the first boundary condition, the solution is 
$$
y(t)=a\exp(-3/4 t)+ct\exp(-3/4t)
$$
for $c$ a constant to be determined. The second condition yields $c=3/4a-1$. Right away, we can see $a>0$ is certainly necessary, and $a\geq 4/3$ is sufficient. The latter ends up being necessary as well.

Now, 
$$
y(t)=a\exp(-3/4 t)+(3/4a-1)t\exp(-3/4t)>0\\
\iff a+(3/4a-1)t>0\\
\iff (1-3/4a)t<a
$$
For this to be valid for $t>0$, and $a>0$, we must have $1-3/4a\leq 0$, or $a\geq 4/3$. $4/3$ is thus your critical value.

Comment: Thank you! Helped alot

Comment: @mathjohnn no problem.